# Convert json column into separate columns

Tags: python, json

```
event_value                                            media_source  campaign  \
0  {"category_name":"technology","phone":"77...      organic       NaN   
1  {"order_price":0,"bonuses":false,"delivery_pri...      organic       NaN   
2  {"item":"{\"product_price\":\"\"}","source":"\...      organic       NaN   
3                                                 {}      organic       NaN
```

I have a database that looks like the one that I attached below
I need to convert json column into multiple columns where keys = column name and values are cell values

Appreciate your help

Comment: it says TypeError: _json_normalize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Comment: I think I was wrong there. What about `pd.json_normalize(df['column_name']` ?

Comment: it return empty data frame it includes only indexes

Comment: could you please add the data of your df to the question? Easier to have a look then.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not valid json data what you got in your rows there.

I used this data as input:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'event_value': 
                   {0: {'category_name': 'Бытовая техника', 'phone': '77'},
                    1: {'order_price': 0, 'bonuses': False, 'delivery_pri': 'stuff'},
                    2: {'item': {'product_price': ''}, 'source': ''},
                    3: {}
                   },
                   'media_source': {0: 'organic', 1: 'organic', 2: 'organic', 3: 'organic'},
                   'campaign': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan}})
print(df)
```

```
                                                     event_value media_source  campaign
0            {'category_name': 'Бытовая техника', 'phone': '77'}      organic       NaN
1  {'order_price': 0, 'bonuses': False, 'delivery_pri': 'stuff'}      organic       NaN
2                  {'item': {'product_price': ''}, 'source': ''}      organic       NaN
3                                                             {}      organic       NaN
```

With this data it works and I think that's what you want to achieve, right ?

```py
res = pd.json_normalize(df['event_value'])
print(res)
```

```
     category_name phone  order_price bonuses delivery_pri source item.product_price
0  Бытовая техника    77          NaN     NaN          NaN    NaN                NaN
1              NaN   NaN          0.0   False        stuff    NaN                NaN
2              NaN   NaN          NaN     NaN          NaN                          
3              NaN   NaN          NaN     NaN          NaN    NaN                NaN
```

Comment: yes but I have css file with this data. So is there a way I can make it the right way? Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience or knowledge with that. Maybe add to the question how you get to this dataFrame. Also a good idea would be to post the data you get when calling `df.to_dict()`, then we don't get only half of the rows continued by `...`